# Running code only after an object is updated in IndexedDB (particularly in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous, cross-browser, indexeddb

I feel like this is a pretty mundane thing to do. I want to update an object in an IndexedDB database and then run some code after which uses the updated values.

What I originally did was just run my callback function after calling `cursor.update`, which works in Firefox. But it fails in Chrome, the update doesn't happen before the following code is run. This is likely a race condition, since (as I understand it) updates are asynchronous.

So then I thought I should use the `onsuccess` signal of `cursor.update` to call my callback function. But much to my surprise, that also doesn't seem to work in Chrome!

Some example code which [you can run on jsFiddle... although amusingly this seems to crash in Firefox in jsFiddle for some reason, but Chrome works fine; for Firefox you can run it locally and it works](http://jsfiddle.net/aQgnq/1/) (this produces output on the JavaScript console in your browser):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var db, request;

request = indexedDB.open("test", 1);
request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
    var i, leagueStore, teams, teamStore;

    db = event.target.result;

    objectStore = db.createObjectStore("objects", {keyPath: "id"});
};
request.onsuccess = function (event) {
    db = request.result;

    // Add some dummy data
    db.transaction("objects", "readwrite").objectStore("objects").put({
        id: 0,
        value: 42
    });

    // Update data
    db.transaction("objects", "readwrite").objectStore("objects").openCursor(0).onsuccess = function (event) {
        var cursor, object;

        cursor = event.target.result;
        object = cursor.value;
        object.value = 43;
        cursor.update(object).onsuccess = function (event) {
            db.transaction("objects").objectStore("objects").get(0).onsuccess = function (event) {
                console.log("Cursor update onsuccess event:");
                console.log(event.target.result);
            };
        };

        // Read back updated data
        db.transaction("objects").objectStore("objects").get(0).onsuccess = function (event) {
            console.log("The line after the cursor update:");
            console.log(event.target.result);
        };

        // Wait a little bit, then read it back
        setTimeout(function () {
            db.transaction("objects").objectStore("objects").get(0).onsuccess = function (event) {
                console.log("After an additional delay via setTimeout:");
                console.log(event.target.result);
            };
        }, 100);
    };
};
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Observed behavior (all on Ubuntu 12.10, FWIW):

In Firefox 19 (current stable version), all three logged objects are identical, with `value` set to 43:

```
The line after the cursor update:
Object {id: 0, value: 43}
Cursor update onsuccess event:
Object {id: 0, value: 43}
After an additional delay via setTimeout:
Object {id: 0, value: 43}
```

In Chrome 25 (current stable version) and 27 (current unstable version), I usually get this output:

```
The line after the cursor update:
Object {id: 0, value: 42}
Cursor update onsuccess event:
Object {id: 0, value: 42}
After an additional delay via setTimeout:
Object {id: 0, value: 43}
```

Sometimes one of the first two outputs is updated to 43, but it's usually a 42.

So again, my question is... how can I run something after the update is actually finished? (That is, without relying on some ridiculous arbitrary delay induced with `setTimeout`.)

Alternative question: Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in Chrome?

Side question: If anyone has IE 10, I wonder how it behaves in this situation..

Comment: I think this was a Chrome bug.  (Or maybe the spec has improved in the last 8 years?).  According to [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#transaction-scheduling) (especially the last bullet point in §2.7.2), the update transaction should complete (and the onsuccess event should fire, and the updated data should be stored) before either of the later two read transactions can start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need setTimeout, just wait transaction to complete as follow:

```
// Update data
var tx = db.transaction("objects", "readwrite");

tx.objectStore("objects").openCursor(0).onsuccess = function (event) {
    var cursor, object;

    cursor = event.target.result;
    object = cursor.value;
    object.value = 43;
    cursor.update(object).onsuccess = function (event) {
        db.transaction("objects").objectStore("objects").get(0).onsuccess = function (event) {
            console.log("Cursor update onsuccess event:");
            console.log(event.target.result);
        };
    };

};

tx.oncomplete = function() {     
    // Read back updated data
    db.transaction("objects").objectStore("objects").get(0).onsuccess = function (event) {
        console.log("The line after the cursor update:");
        console.log(event.target.result);
   };
 }
```

This is one of the confusing aspect of IndexedDB API. Request onsuccess don't not mean your success is written to the database. Only transaction oncomplete confirm it. The reason is, you can still abort transaction `tx.abort()` after write request.

Comment: Thanks. An ancillary question then.. is there any use whatsoever for the onsuccess signal of an update? Or is it just there to confuse me?

Answer (score 0):

I used the promise pattern to avoid the settimeout and [JayData library](http://jaydata.org) to unify the data access and hide cursor API.
After including the library (include.jaydata.org/jaydata.min.js) the snippet looks like this ([online jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JayData/23WCb/)):

```
$data.Entity.extend("Todo", {
    Id: { type: "int", key: true, computed: true },
    Task: { type: String, required: true, maxLength: 200 }
});

$data.EntityContext.extend("TodoDatabase", {
    Todos: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: Todo }
});

var todoDB = new TodoDatabase({ 
    provider: 'indexedDb', databaseName: 'MyTodoDatabase'
});

todoDB.onReady(function() {
    var newTodo = new Todo({Task: "alma"});
    todoDB.Todos.add(newTodo);
    todoDB.saveChanges()
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Initial value: ", newTodo.Task);
        todoDB.Todos.attach(newTodo);
        newTodo.Task = "korte";
        return todoDB.Todos.saveChanges();
    })
    .then(function(){
        console.log("Updated value: ", newTodo.Task);
        return todoDB.Todos
        .filter(function(t) {return t.Id == item.Id;}, {item: newTodo})
        .toArray(function(dbResult){
            var todoFromDb = dbResult[0];
            console.log("Value from DB: ", todoFromDb.Task);
        });
    })


});
```

It's much less code and you only have to change the type of the provider to change to WebSQL :)