# Why is indexedDB not showing new entries in Chrome

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Im using the [indexDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB) API with an HTML5 form. For some reason when I add a new entry into it, it display right away in Firefox but in Chrome is do not show until I refresh the page.

JS:

```
var mainForm, fName, lName, uName, pass, email, dob, phone, bio, nl, terms, school, gender, save, reset, db;

function startDB(){
    mainForm = document.getElementById('mainForm');
    fname = document.getElementById('fName');
    lName = document.getElementById('lName');
    users = document.getElementById('uName');
    pass = document.getElementById('password');
    email = document.getElementById('email');
    dob = document.getElementById('dob');
    phone = document.getElementById('phone');
    bio = document.getElementById('bio');
    nl = document.getElementById('newsletter');
    terms = document.getElementById('terms');
    school = document.getElementById('school');
    gender = document.getElementsByName('gender');
    save = document.getElementById('save');
    reset = document.getElementById('reset'); 
    databox = document.getElementById('databox');

    save.addEventListener('click',addObject);

    //open DB
    var request = indexedDB.open('macroPlay'); 
    //if fails
    request.addEventListener('error', showerror); 
    //if succeeds
    request.addEventListener('success', start); 
    //if !exist, create.
    request.addEventListener('upgradeneeded', createdb); 
}
function showerror(e){
    alert('Error: ' + e.code + ' - ' + e.message);
}
function start(e){
    db = e.target.result;
    showUsers();// Show all values in the object store
}
function createdb(e){
    var datababase = e.target.result;
    var myusers = datababase.createObjectStore('users', {keyPath: 'userName'});
}
function addObject(){
    var fName = document.getElementById('fName').value;
    var lName = document.getElementById('lName').value;
    var userName = document.getElementById('uName').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var dob = document.getElementById('dob').value;
    var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
    var bio = document.getElementById('bio').value;
    var nl = document.getElementById('nl').value;
    var terms = document.getElementById('terms').value;
    var school = document.getElementById('school').value;

    //May need to set a loop to find value of radio
    var gender;
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('gender');

    for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            gender=radios[i].value;
        }
    }

    //set up transaction
    var mytransaction = db.transaction(['users'], "readwrite"); 

    //get object store
    var myusers = mytransaction.objectStore('users'); 

    //Add item
    var request = myusers.add(new getUser(userName,fName,lName,pass,email,dob,phone,bio,nl,terms,school,gender));

    // Show all results.
    request.addEventListener('success', showUsers);     

    //Reset Form Fields
    clearForm();

}
function getUser(userName, fn, ln, pw, em, dob, tel, bio, nl,tm, scl, gender){
    this.userName = userName;
    this.fn = fn;
    this.ln = ln;
    this.pw = pw;
    this.em = em;
    this.dob = dob;
    this.tel = tel;
    this.bio = bio;
    this.nl = nl;
    this.tm = tm;
    this.scl = scl;
    this.gender = gender;
}
function showUsers(){
    //reset box
    databox.innerHTML = ''; 
    //set the transaction 
    var mytransaction = db.transaction(['users']);
    //get object store
    var myusers = mytransaction.objectStore('users');
    //open the cursor and set an order
    var newcursor = myusers.openCursor(null,"prev");
    //show all users on successful load of DB
    newcursor.addEventListener('success',showUserList);
}
function showUserList(e){
    //var result = e.target.result;
    //databox.innerHTML = '<div>' + result.id + ' - ' + result.name + ' - ' + result.date + '</div>';
    var cursor = e.target.result; // Capture multiple return values as a cursor

    // Modify the databox to show the results 
    if (cursor){
        databox.innerHTML += '<div>' + 
        cursor.value.userName + ' - ' + 
        cursor.value.fn+ ' - ' + 
        cursor.value.ln+ ' - '+ 
        cursor.value.pw+ ' - '+ 
        cursor.value.em+ ' - '+ 
        cursor.value.dob+ ' - '+
        cursor.value.tel+ ' - '+ 
        cursor.value.bio+ ' - '+ 
        cursor.value.nl+ ' - '+
        cursor.value.tm+ ' - '+
        cursor.value.scl+' - '+
        cursor.value.gender+ 
        ' <input type="button" onclick="removeobject(\'' + cursor.value.userName + '\')" value="remove"/></div>';
            // Add a remove button as inserted HTML
        cursor.continue(); // Iterates over the cursor
    }
}
function removeobject(keyword){
    // Confirm the deletion
    if(confirm('Are you sure?')){ 
        // Set the transaction
        var mytransaction = db.transaction(['users'], "readwrite"); 
        // Get the object store
        var mystore = mytransaction.objectStore('users'); 
        // Delete the record with the chosen index
        var request = mystore.delete(keyword); 
        // If success, show the updated results
        request.addEventListener('success', showUsers); 
    }
}
//reset functions
function clearForm(){
    //Reset form
    fname = document.getElementById('fName').value='';
    lName = document.getElementById('lName').value='';
    uName = document.getElementById('uName').value='';
    pass = document.getElementById('password').value='';
    email = document.getElementById('email').value='';
    dob = document.getElementById('dob').value='';
    phone = document.getElementById('phone').value='';
    bio = document.getElementById('bio').value='';
    nl = document.getElementById('nl').value='';
    terms = document.getElementById('terms').value='';
    school = document.getElementById('school').value='';
    gender = document.getElementsByName('gender').value='';
    showUserList(); 
}
function reset(){
    if(confirm("are you sure?")){
        var f = document.getElementById("mainForm");
        f.reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your Chrome browser version? IndexedDB starts working on v24

Comment: Version 25.0.1364.172 m. I assumed Chrome updated on it's own. IndexedDB works it's just not updating in real-time for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your write transaction probably isn't finishing before your read transaction runs.  `add` is asynchronous so it isn't guaranteed to finish before you move on, [even if you listen to the `success` signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151242/running-code-only-after-an-object-is-updated-in-indexeddb-particularly-in-chrom). To fix this, you have two options:

Option 1:

Use the same transaction by passing it from `addObject` to `showUsers`.

Option 2:

Wait for the first transaction to completely finish, which guarantees the data is written before moving on. So, change

```
    request.addEventListener('success', showUsers);
```

to something like

```
    mytransaction.addEventListener('complete', showUsers);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and lead to more information on the IndexedDB so thank you very much.